# puppet matching multiple agent hostnames to params.pp data structure

Tags: wso2, puppet, wso2-as

I have a module called `appserver` in my puppet modules.
In that module manifests I have a `params.pp` file which is inherited by `init.pp` file.
In `params.pp` file I have the following data structure.

```
$servers = {
                appserver-mgr => { axis2   => {subDomain => 'mgt',},
                                    carbon  => {subDomain => 'mgt',},
                                    serverOptions => '-Dsetup',
                                    server_home => $carbon_home, },
                appserver-wkr => { axis2   => {subDomain => 'worker', members => ['appserver-mgr2-ip']},
                                    carbon => {subDomain => 'worker',},
                                    serverOptions => '-DworkerNode=true',
                                    server_home => $carbon_home, },
        }
```

In my `init.pp` file I'm filling my templates as follows using the said data structure.

```
    define fill_templates($axis2, $carbon, $clustering, $serverOptions, $server_home) {
            $ipAdd = $::ipaddress
            $hostName = $::hostname
            if $hostName == "${name}" {
                    notify {"host name match found for $hostName for $ipAdd":}
                    file {  "${server_home}/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml":
                            ensure  => file,
                            content => template('appserver/axis2.xml.erb'),
                    }
                    ->
                    file {  "${server_home}/repository/conf/carbon.xml":
                            ensure  => file,
                            content => template('appserver/carbon.xml.erb'),
                    }
                    ->
                    file {  "${server_home}/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml":
                            ensure  => file,
                            content => template('appserver/catalina-server.xml.erb'),
                    }
            }
    }
```

As per the current method, if a matching node is found (say `appserver-mgr`) the respective data structure values are retrieved and applied to the templates.
Currently these scripts are working as expected.

Now I want to change it as follows.

I have a cluster containing following nodes.

```
appserver-mgr-1
appserver-mgr-2
appserver-mgr-3

appserver-wkr-1
appserver-wkr-2
appserver-wkr-3
appserver-wkr-4
appserver-wkr-5
```

By using the same data structure in `params.pp` file, how can I apply the `appserver-mgr` configuration to `*.mgr` nodes 1-3 and `appserver-wkr` configuration to `*.wkr` nodes 1-5?

Can I use regular expressions for this task?

Comment: I've done something similar before with ``create_resources()``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure that it would be possible to bend the Puppet DSL to do what you need here. However, the far better approach to this issue is Hiera.

```
node /appserver-mgr/ {
    $node_class    = 'appserver'
    $node_subclass = 'manager'
}
node /appserver-wrk/ {
    $node_class    = 'appserver'
    $node_subclass = 'worker'
}
```

Use the `node_class` and `node_subclass` variables in your Hierarchy.

```
# /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: /etc/puppet/hieradata
:hierarchy:
  - "%{::clientcert}"
  - "class-%{node_class}-%{node_subclass}"
  - "class-%{node_class}"
  - common
```

Now you can define your data right in the YAML for Hiera, instead of `params.pp`.

```
# /etc/puppet/hieradata/class-appserver-manager.yaml
servers:
  axis2:
    subDomain: mgt
  carbon:
    subDomain: mgt
  serverOptions: -Dsetup
  server_home: %{carbon_home}
```

and for the worker:

```
 # /etc/puppet/hieradata/class-appserver-worker.yaml
 servers:
   axis2:
     subDomain: worker
     members: 
       - appserver-mgr2-ip
     carbon:
       subDomain: worker
   serverOptions: -DworkerNode=true
   server_home: %{carbon_home}
```

In your `params` class, the following then suffices:

```
$servers = hiera('servers')
```

Or you don't even bother with the `params` class, and just replace the uses of the `$servers` variable with `hiera` calls. But doing just one call in a `params` style class is a good practice.

**Note:** Using the variable value `%{carbon_home}` from Hiera is somewhat dangerous, you might want to hardcode the actual value in the YAML there.